# Getting Data from row which button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following ajax that needs to pass the userID to a PHP script.

```
document.getElementById("delete").addEventListener("click", function(){
 if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user's account?")) {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'deleteUser.php?id='+<?php echo $userID ?>,
    success: function(data) {
    toastr.danger("User successfully deleted!");
  }
});
 } else {

 }
});
```

I'm unsure how to actually get the row data from the button used since they're posted in the TD of each row as it goes through each record in the set. How would one accomplish this?

```
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                  <thead class="thead-dark">
                                    <tr>

                                      <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                                      <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                                      <th scope="col">Email</th>
                                      <th scope="col">Username</th>
                                      <th scope="col">Account Type</th>
                                      <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                                    </tr>
                                  </thead>
                                  <tbody>

                                        <?php

                                        $query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE company ='".$res['company']."' ")->fetchall();

                                        foreach($query as $row){
                                            echo '   <tr>';

                                            echo '   <td>'.$row['fname'].'</td>' ;
                                            echo '   <td>'.$row['lname'].'</td>' ;
                                            echo '   <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>' ;
                                            echo '   <td>'.$row['account_name'].'</td>' ;
                                            echo '   <td>'.$row['user_type'].'</td>' ;
                                            echo '   <td><button id="delete" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>';
                                            echo '   <button id="edit" type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></button> </td>';
                                            echo '   </tr>';


                                        } 
                                        ?>

                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:
**php:**

```
foreach($query as $row){
   echo '   <tr>';

    echo '   <td>'.$row['fname'].'</td>' ;
    echo '   <td>'.$row['lname'].'</td>' ;
    echo '   <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>' ;
    echo '   <td>'.$row['account_name'].'</td>' ;
    echo '   <td>'.$row['user_type'].'</td>' ;
    echo '   <td><button data-id="' . $row['id'] . '" type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>';
    echo '   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info edit"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></button> </td>';
  echo '   </tr>';
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$("button.delete").each(function(){
 $(this).on('click', function(e){
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user's account?")) {
       $.ajax({
          url: 'deleteUser.php?id='+$(this).data('id'),
          success: function(data) {
             toastr.danger("User successfully deleted!");
          }
       });
    } else {
       //do something else
    }
 }); 
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. The only issue I have is the toastr notification doesn't show up and isn't throwing any errors in DevTools. Any ideas? I changed it from .danger to success because I found out it wasn't an actual item (danger)

Comment: I did. I'm using the same code that works on other pages. I Iguess if I look at toastr.min.js it shows 302 internal redirect

Comment: EDIT: I got it, I forgot to load the css *FACEPAAAALM

Answer (score 0):

HTML 4.01 specification says ID must be document-wide unique.

HTML 5 specification says the same thing but in other words. It says that ID must be unique in its home subtree, which is basically the document if we read the definition of it.

I'd fix that first: `<button id="delete"` needs to be unique

Next - I'd add an onClick to your delete button so you have `<button onclick="deleteUser(2);"`

Then, I'd rewrite your listener registration to just be a function:

```
function deleteUser(id){
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user's account?")) {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'deleteUser.php?id='+<?php echo $userID ?>,
    success: function(data) {
    toastr.danger("User successfully deleted!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, anyway you need to edit this line `url: 'deleteUser.php?id='+<?php echo $userID ?>,` <-- to `id`